# Prove $S_Nf=\sum_{|j|\le N} \hat f(j) e^{ijx}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(C(\mathbb T),||.||_{\infty})$

Tags: real-analysis

I know if $f\in C(\mathbb T) \quad $and$\quad \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)|<\infty$ then the Fourier series uniformly converges to $f$

I want to prove the first step of the proof showing that the partial sum  $S_Nf$ is a Cauchy sequence

I want estimate the difference between $S_N f$ and $S_M f$ with $M>N$.

$|(S_M f)(x)-(S_N f)(x)|=|\sum_{N<|j|\le M}\hat f(j) e^{ijx} |\le\sum_{N<|j|\le M}|\hat f(j)|<\sum_{|j|\ge N+1}|\hat{f}(j)|=\sum_{|j|\ge N+1}\frac{|\hat{f{^k}}(j)|}{|j|^k}$

For the Schwartz inequality :

$|(S_M f)(x)-(S_N f)(x)|\le\left(\sum_{|j|\ge N+1} \frac{1}{|j|^{2k}}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{|j|\in \mathbb Z}{|\hat{f{^k}}(j)|^2}\right)^{1/2}=\left(\sum_{|j|\ge N+1} \frac{1}{|j|^{2k}}\right)^{1/2} ||f^k||_{L^2(\mathbb T)}$

I calculate then $\left(\sum_{|j|\ge N+1} \frac{1}{|j|^{2k}}\right)<2\int_{N+1}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{2k}}=\frac{2}{2k-1}\frac{1}{(N+1)^{2k-1}}$

and I found $|(S_M f)(x)-(S_N f)(x)|\le\sqrt{\frac{2}{2k-1}}\frac{1}{(N+1)^{2k-1}}||f^k||_{L^2(\mathbb T)}$

so $\{S_N f\}$
 is a Cauchy sequence?It's right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a more general result: given the hypothesis, you want to prove that $S_nf(x)\to f(x).$ Since $\sum |\hat f(n)|<\infty,$ the function $g(x)=\sum \hat f(n)e^{int}$ converges everywhere, and now the triangle inequality yields $|S_Nf(x)-g(x)|\le \sum_{|n|>N}|\hat f(n)|$, which shows that $S_nf$ converges $\textit{uniformly}$ to $g$. So, $S_nf$ is uniformly Cauchy. But we can say more: by the above result, we have

$\hat g(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb T}g(x)e^{-inx}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb T}\left(\sum_{k} \hat f(k)e^{ikx}\right)e^{-inx}dt= \int_{\mathbb T}f(n)e^{int}=\hat f(n)$ where we have used orthonormality of the $\{e^{int}\}_n$ for the next to last equality.

Thus, $f$ and $g$ have the same Fourier coefficients and so $f=g$ almost everywhere. But since $f$ is assumed continuous, in fact $f=g$ so we have that $S_nf\to f$ uniformly on $\mathbb T$.

Comment: I don't understand.My initial proof is wrong?

Comment: the partial sums $s_n(f,x)$ do converge to $f$ in the $L^2$ norm, so a subsequence converges pointwise to $f$ a.e. but I do not think you can say anything more. Or am I misreading your question.?

Comment: for hyphotesis  $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)|<\infty$ so is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: I misread your question. I do not understand your proof. Please see my answer.

Comment: $\\\int_{\mathbb T}f(t)D_N(x-t)dt$ why is a Cauchy sequence?